# How to browse Office 365 sharepoint site with a host record in DNS

Tags: 2013, office-365, dns

We have on prem sharepoint 2013 running as http://abc within our organization. We are now in process of migrating out site to office365 tenant and our domainurl is preety long compared to existing one. https://abc.xyz.com

Our users are just so fond of typing "abc" in browser. Can we still use abc to browse our office365 sharepoint site after migration? If we can how can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

An Office365 SharePoint-URL always looks like this: https://tenantname.sharepoint.com. You cannot change this URL - so choose your tenant-name wisely! There is no direct way to let your users use http://abc.

Some ideas for workarounds (with pro and con!):

- Create a CNAME in your local DNS called "abc". I tried this some time ago and it didn't work. Just got some HTTP Code 200 without any useful content.
- Host a small OnPremise Website and configure it to listen to http://abc. Use a [HTTP Redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) to move your users to SharePoint-Online. This only works if your users type "http://abc" in their browsers. Does not work if users have browser-bookmarks, connected lists to outlook (contacts, tasks, ..) or shortcuts (open-in-explorer, ..). You could improve this simple solution with [URL-Rewritng](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

My recommendation:
Get rid of your existing URL. It may be a lot of work during migration, but in the long term it saves you a lot of hassle.